# Divisiblity by prime

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Find minimum positive integer pair $(x,y)$ such that $P$ divides $|C^x−D^y|$.
Here $P$ is a prime number and $C$ and $D$ are constants which are provided to us.

For example, if $P=7$,$C=1$,$D=5$, the minimum positive pair is $(x,y)=(1,6)$

(as $7$ divides $∣1^1−5^6∣=15624=7\times2232$).

How to approach this problem? Also how to check if such a pair exists or not?
I mean if in above example $C=8$ and $D=7$ then there is no such pair possible.

Comment: How exactly do you define the minimum of the pair $(x/y)$?

Comment: What is the order on the integer pairs? Suppose $p$ would divide both $C^2 - D^5$ and $C^3-D^3$, would $(2,5)$ or $(3,3)$ count as smaller?

Comment: sorry i did not mention it...We are defining minimum pair(x,y) if for given positive constants A and B ,Ax+By is minimum.(A,B will be provided)

Comment: for above example take A=1 , B=1

Comment: If neither $C$ nor $D$ is a multiple of $P$, then the pair $(P-1,P-1)$ is a solution due to Fermat's little theorem. If $C$ and $D$ are both multiples of $P$, the pair $(1,1)$ is a solution. In the other cases (one constant is a multiple of $P$ and one not), there is obviously no solution.

Comment: i will study fermat little theorem to understand your point..Thank you for your response

Comment: For large $P$, it is probably very hard to find the minimum solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter noted, $(P-1,P-1)$ is a solution if $P$ does not divide either $C$ or $D$.  You can then calculate the values of $C^x, D^y \pmod P$ up through $P-1$ and search for a match.  This is of order $P^2$ in calculation because you have that many comparisons.